# codeigniter/postgres throw errors when trying to insert timestamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I'm trying to use this code, plus codeigniter to

```
$data = array(
 // 'category' => $dbi['category'],
    'transaction_timestamp' => time(),
);

$this->db->insert('bitzon', $data);
```

Error given:

```
 A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

ERROR: column "transaction_timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone but        expression is of type integer"
```

Why is this?

Comment: instead of `time()` use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Comment: thank you very much. I think I'm done!

Can you tell me why `time()` doesn't work?

Comment: time() returns a unix timestamp: seconds since jan 1/1970, which is just an integer. timestamp/datetime fields in mysql expect a date/time **STRING** in a `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `date()` to convert it into a proper datetime format instead of `time()` which returns as integer

```
$data = array(
  // 'category' => $dbi['category'],
  'transaction_timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);

$this->db->insert('bitzon', $data);
```